# Debug postprocessor to get the response data of immediate/recent sample

Tags: jmeter

Trying to get all the viewstates(count 25) of a sample2 using reg expression(using match no. -1) and debug postprocessor. The previous sample1 has also viewstates(count 10) which i am exracting one by one using reg expression.

The debug postprocessor of sample2 extracting 10 viewstates of sample1 first and then the remaining 15 from sample2. The matchNr count is correct and first 10 values are not from sample2.

How can i make the debug postprocessor to get the viewstates only from sample2?

Comment: You can use different reference name

Comment: used different reference name and it worked.

Comment: I added an answer

Answer (score 0):

[Debug PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_PostProcessor) respects [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-scoping-rules-the-ultimate-guide) so if you want to see JMeter Variables specific only to `sample2` - add Debug Post-Processors **as a child** of the `sample2`

[image: JMeter Scoping Rules]

This way it will be applied only to `sample2` and you will see JMeter Variables specific to this sampler.

Comment: Yes, I used debug postprocessor as a child of sample2 and used different reference name. It's still extracting the previous sample1 viewstates. If I disable sample1 reg exp of viewstates, it's showing the viewstates extracted from sample0.